# For ARM-cortex M4 Black Pill

Tags: embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I used the Pins of PORTA as an output, My question is "Is there any certain pins in PORTA may cause any burn or communication problems like not detecting the ST-Link device?"

and How can I erase the flash memory manually on the board?

I tried to hold the NRST for few seconds, and the key boot, then I read that this button changes the Mc mode to the boot mode, So How could I now in which mode the Mc in ?